# Combining multiple regression models and finding most important predictors

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression

I have a data set for each facebook post on my page, each dataset containing the same predictors. I am looking to find the most important factors driving the cost_per_like so that I can adjust my budget accordingly.

Since the content of each post is different, I am assuming that I cannot combine all the data and do a regression analysis (please correct me if I'm wrong).

My question is how should I perform a regression analysis (what technique / algorithm) in this scenario? I was thinking I'd perform a regression analysis on each dataset and somehow combine the overall results but I am not sure how to go about it or even if it is the right approach.

EDIT: I've attached sample data from two different posts. There are around 80 variables so I just included only a few. This is just one row data for each post. The number of rows for each post varies. This data is sampled over 10 minute intervals for one week. I am looking to find the most important predictors and their coefficients which can model the cost_per_like response.

```
cost_per_inline_link_click  |  post id  |  cost_per_like    |  cost_per_comment |  cost_per_link_click  |  cost_per_post_like
    1.30                    |     123   |  165              |  5580             |       1.3             |  16.9
.
.
.


cost_per_inline_link_click  |  post id  |  cost_per_like    |  cost_per_comment |  cost_per_link_click  |  cost_per_post_like
    1.40                    |     456   |  155              |  5980             |       9.3             |  26.9
.
.
.
```

Comment: I don't quite follow your situation (or maybe your reasoning). Could you post a small example dataset to illustrate your question?

Comment: @gung I've added a small snippet of data from the datasets of two different posts. I have around a 100 datasets and my objective is to find out what are the most important factors influencing the cost_per_like so that I can adjust my advertising budget accordingly.